# How to use remote laptop in RAID with ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, rsync

I have a laptop A where I'm goint to install Ubuntu Server configuring it with 2 disks in RAID1.
I have another laptop B in a different building ( with public and static IP ) with an external USB HDD.

I'm wondering how to add to the RAID1 of the laptop A, the external HDD of the laptop B.

Is it possibile?

Should I use rsync?

I'd like a setup where if one of the two laptops stolen, it could be replaced by the other one...

Thank you in advance,
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

[DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) may be a solution for your problem. Or any other clustered filesystem.